# Sending live activity push notifications using Java with Pushy library not working

Tags: java, spring, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement live activity push notifications in my Java application using the Pushy library. However, I'm facing issues and the notifications are not being delivered successfully.

```
            String fileName = "<XXX.p8>";
            String teamID = "<TEAM_ID>";
            String keyID = "<KEY_ID>";
            String topic = "<bundleID>";
            String cirt = this.getClass().getResource(fileName).getFile();
            String tk = "<DEVICE_TOKEN>";
            log.info("cirt file : {} ", cirt);
            if (!new File(cirt).exists()) {
                throw new NotFoundException(NotFound.APNSNOTFOUND, Boolean.TRUE);
            }
            final ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder().setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST)
                    .setSigningKey(ApnsSigningKey.loadFromPkcs8File(new File(cirt), teamID, keyID)).build();
            SimpleApnsPushNotification pushNotification = null;
            {
                final String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"timestamp\":1685577599,\"event\":\"update\",\"relevance-score\":75.0,\"stale-date\":1650998941,\"content-state\":{\"flightStatus\":\"Arrived!\",\"statusColor\":\"green\",\"estimatedTime\":1659416400},\"alert\":{\"title\":\"Delivery Update\",\"body\":\"Your pizza order will arrive soon.\",\"sound\":\"example.aiff\"}}}";
                final String token = TokenUtil.sanitizeTokenString(tk);
                pushNotification = new SimpleApnsPushNotification(token, topic, payload);
                log.info("topic : {}", pushNotification.getTopic());
                final PushNotificationFuture<SimpleApnsPushNotification, PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification>> sendNotificationFuture = apnsClient
                        .sendNotification(pushNotification);
                sendNotificationFuture.whenComplete((response, cause) -> {
                    if (response.isAccepted()) {
                        System.out.println("Push notification accepted by APNs gateway.");
                    } else {
                        System.out
                                .println("Notification rejected by the APNs gateway: " + response.getRejectionReason());

                        response.getTokenInvalidationTimestamp().ifPresent(timestamp -> {
                            System.out.println("\t…and the token is invalid as of " + timestamp);
                        });
                    }
                    apnsClient.close();
                });
            }
```

I have replaced ,<TEAM_ID>,<KEY_ID>  with my actual Pushy API key and <DEVICE_TOKEN> with the target device token. However, the notification is not being received by the device.

I would appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to successfully send live activity push notifications using Java with the Pushy library.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The topic value should be `<bundleID>.push-type.liveactivity` format.